# Can't create TPL Function from PHP Code using Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have created a function to run an SQL query, output the data and that seems fine, Problem is I can't do anything with it now since i can't make the output to the templates work.

PHP Code:

```
 function getCategories() {
    try {
        foreach($this->pdo->query("SELECT categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description FROM categories") as $row) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!:" . $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
    return $rows;
    $smarty = new Smarty();
    $smarty->assign('categories', $rows);
}
```

Which simply returns this:

[image]

Replacing `return $rows;` with `return $smarty->assign('categories', $rows);` simply renders a blank page.

I'm using this in the template: `{$categories.cat_name}`

Can anyone help me fix this?

I'm trying to rewrite a vulnerable crappy forum script using Smarty so it's a base worth trying to develop a script off of. It's literally just categories, topics and a login / register system atm that I'm trying to rewrite using Smarty.

Comment: Can you show us the html where you want to use categories?

Comment: The HTML is irrelevant to the matter because Smarty has to declare the variable for this to even work... Your supposed to use "$smarty->assign('categories', $rows);" to assign the $categories. variable and then add the rest after the (dot) so that Smarty pulls the info from that row. 

Smarty does it differently than PHP itself. The php is the only relevant matter to this..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create a new smarty object, assign it a variable, but doesn't use it to display your template - so this object get lost.

I suggest to pass the Smarty object to your function like this:

```
function getCategories(&$smarty) {
    $rows = array();
    if($result = $this->pdo->query("SELECT categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description FROM categories")) {
        $rows = $result->fetchAll();
    }
    $smarty->assign('categories', $rows);
}
```

This way the object reference will be passed to the function - you will be able to assign any vars you want to it without the need of returning it. Just be sure that you send the Smarty object you use to render the template.

Comment: Ok but how would i actually run the query and return the results in order for this to even work? Because i haven't actually been able to make this work.. i attempted this before but cannot find any existing code or examples of how the SQL query is executed and outputted to a row other than with a catch and in the end i end up with my existing code that doesn't work...

Because if i do this: http://i.imgur.com/FIWlM73.png
then i end up with http://i.imgur.com/VuEVH4j.png

& if i try $sql = query then i get an $sql error for variable and i want to use PDO anyways...

Comment: You're using wrong PDO - you should fetch the result to get an array. [`PDO::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) return a [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object, which need to be fetched with [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) for example. I updated my answer to give an example of a correct use of PDO.

Comment: Awesome! I thought it was going to work finally. & then 

http://i.imgur.com/nXI9NfQ.pngS

Line 51: 
     'code' if($result = $this->pdo->query->("SELECT categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description FROM categories")) {

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code to see where the syntax error comes from?

Comment: the updated code is the same as above.. http://i.imgur.com/BYxVwm4.png the synax error comes from line 51 which i listed above..

Comment: Ok there was a `->` after `query` that shouldn't be here. Please check updated code.